# Apache different sites on different ports, still links to same site. Bind9 for domain names

Tags: apache, apache2, port, bind, virtualhost

I've been trying to create 3 different domains linking to 3 different sites on the same machine, 2 which works but the third on the different port links to the first page.

My apache config looks like this:

```
Listen 81
NameVirtualHost *:81
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName controlpanel.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/controlpanel
</VirtualHost>
```

I've used Bind9 to set up the domains.

```
www     IN      A       123.123.123.123
www2    IN      A       123.123.123.123
controlpanel   IN      A       123.123.123.123
```

www and www2 works fine and shows the correct site, however controlpanel.example.com also links to the first www site. When I enter the port manualy on the ip, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:81, i get linked correctly. The thing is that I don't really know where I'm doing it wrong, this is the first time I'm trying anything like this. You got any ideas?

Im also running this on an old ubuntu 12.04 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding where you're going in the comments for the previous answer:

You could add a port 80 virtualhost for controlpanel.example.com  and put a single statement inside,

```
Redirect / http://controlpanel.example.com:81
```

The purpose of the ServerName is not to inform the browser what port your webserver is using.  It's used for name-based virtualhosts and as a last resort for self-referential links (out of the box, self-referential links are generated with whatever the client already thought it was accessing via the Host: header)

But there is definitely something quite bizarre about your requirement. Usually the motivation is to not use custom ports, and if they are, to address the server with a low port and have the por remapped by some intermediary (load balancer, proxy).

Comment: Yea the port isnt really specific, I've tried diffrent but gotten nowhere so I just choosed to use one that's easy to remember. But redirect seems to be a way to do it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your third virtualhost to be simulataneously the defautl on port 81 and a name-based option on port 80:

Change

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:81>
```

Apache finds the set of virtual hosts with the best IP:PORT based match first, then if NameVirtualHost also matches, starts looking at the ServerNames from that set.

Comment: No I just want it to connect on port 81 when I enter controlpanel.example.com. Now it just shows me the same results as if I were to enter www.example.com

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think any browser is willing to second-guess the port in the URL.  The default port for HTTP is 80 and you omit the port from your URL.  How do you expect it to guess 81?

Comment: I think you missunderstand my question, its not suppose to guess 81, thats the whole problem, apache should automatically choose port 81 when you enter controlpanel.example.com. thats the whole point of creating the virtual server on port 81 isnt it? To not make the user having to manually enter the port, which he would have no idea what port it was unless i specifically told it.
If you enter www.example.com apache should redirect you to the files in folder www through port 80, and if you enter controlpanel.example.com apache should redirect you to the files in controlpanel through the port 81

Comment: Sorry, there are just too many misconceptions here to really address individually. 

There are lots of intermediary things that can allow a webserver to listen on alternate ports but still be addressed by the standard ports (HTTP proxies, IP sprayers, NAT devices, network firewall software running in the host).

Fundamentally, if you just want to discriminate based on hostname, you shouldn't be using non-standard ports for no good reason, just use basic name-based virtualhosts.

Comment: ergo controlpanel.example.com should give you the same results as typing www.example.com:81. but without the admin having to guess port 81

Comment: I still think your missunderstanding the question, the server listens to the port fine, connecting to the server and manually typing port 81 works fine, everything works fine, besides typing the url controlpanel.example.com, the virtual host is set to the port which works fine, its just that the server doesnt uunderstand that controlpanel.example.com should give the same results as www.example.com:81

Comment: Why bother with port 81 at all?  The answer makes the port optional, what are you giving up there?

Comment: I understand the requirement, the server is listening just fine but you've never told your browser to connect to that port.  Your virtualhost configuration discriminates based on the port, and it's not a match.

Comment: So you're saying that there is no way to connect to a site that is run on a different port except if the user manually tells the browser to connect to that port? There is no way apache can tell the browser that its port 81?

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of using a "servername"? to make the browser understand that when entering a specific url it should connect through a specific port? Well in this case at least, but its meant to redirect you to different places depending on what the user enters